# using adb command for Samung Galaxty A51

Tags: usb, debug

I have a samsung galaxy A51 i already had the developer mode on my phone but i forgot to allow usb debugging on it before my screen broke. The phone still works but the screen wont light up & wont come on. I download the android debugging bridge. I dont even know how to work the commands. Can anyone please help. I am trying to get everything off the phone & save it to my comouter. I am currently running a Windows 10 program. I habve the acer spin 3 computer

Comment: kindly check [broken-screen](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/broken-screen/info) questions